# clear parent and keep transform not working

Tags: rigging

I'm trying to separate a mesh from its armature after transforming it. I use Clear Parent and Keep Transform, but when I delete the armature, the mesh reverts back to its original state. Any suggestions for this problem?

Comment: Hello and welcome. First apply the armature modifier of the mesh object before the armature is deleted.